# C# console application design like htop

Tags: c#, console, console-application, windows-console

I want to build console application with similar interface like htop's one (fixed console design). Here is a link to htop console design: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Htop.png. I wanted to ask how can I build application like this as I only know C#'s `Console.Write()` method. I am writing simple program that is starting up applications via `Process.Start()` and then I am monitoring for example their RAM usage via `Process.WorkingSet64` and outputing it via simple `Console.WriteLine()` each line to console. But how could I design C# console application like htop so it has fixed design that will be for example refreshing every 1 second. By fixed designed I mean that I it will be fixed position on the console where I will print out process names, ram usage, application name, etc. Here is my code of the program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] myApps = { "notepad.exe", "calc.exe", "explorer.exe" };

        Thread w;
        ParameterizedThreadStart ts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(StartMyApp);
        foreach (var myApp in myApps)
        {
            w = new Thread(ts);
            w.Start(myApp);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public static void StartMyApp(object myAppPath)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo myInfoProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
        myInfoProcess.FileName = myAppPath.ToString();
        myInfoProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
        Process myProcess = Process.Start(myInfoProcess);

        do
        {
            if (!myProcess.HasExited)
            {
                myProcess.Refresh(); // Refresh the current process property values.
                Console.WriteLine(myProcess.ProcessName+" RAM: " + (myProcess.WorkingSet64 / 1024 / 1024).ToString() + "\n");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        while (!myProcess.WaitForExit(1000)); 
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Thanks for pointing to `Console.SetCursorPosition` @Jim Mischel. I want to use that in my application but now I have another problem. How could I pass to my `StartMyApp` method, the index number from `myApps` array so I could do something like:

```
Console.WriteLine((Array.IndexOf(myApps, myAppPath) + " " + myProcess.ProcessName+" RAM: "+ (myProcess.WorkingSet64 / 1024 / 1024).ToString() + "\n");
```

That is inside my `StartMyApp` method. Any method I use I end up getting `The name 'myApps' does not exist in the current context`. This is very important for me so I could design my application later using `Console.SetCursorPosition` but I need that index number. So my output would be for example:

```
0 notepad RAM: 4
1 calc RAM: 4
2 explorer RAM: 12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call [Console.SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set the position where the next write will occur. The linked MSDN topic has a basic example that will get you started.

You'll also be interested in the `BackgroundColor`, `ForegroundColor`, and possibly other properties. See the [Console class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation for details.

Comment: thanks for pointing to `Console.SetCursorPosition`. I've got another question (EDIT) :)